# How to create a XML file using JSP/HTML and XSLT

Tags: html, xml, jsp, xslt

I've already created some html code using a XML file and based on a XSLT template.

Howerver, this time I need to create an inverse process (i.e., based on HTML code, create a XML file).

Plus, I need to create some quiz like:

**Personal Info**

**Name**:___

**Age**:____

etc... with input tags and stuff like that in a JSP file (or HTML). Then, after an user interaction and click on submit, this form need to create a XML file with this schema

```
<Personal Info>
   <name>...</name>
   <age>...</age>
   ...
</Personal Info>
```

In the future, this XML doc will be inserted in Form attribute on Java, through Controller, and persisted in database.

Thanks

João Vicente

Comment: it is possible to make this mapping using xslt too? how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use java script for reading the user inputs from html and build xml.